# Travelling to US with United Airlines with only one first name and only one last name

Tags: passports, tickets

I'm flying for the first time to US with a passport. Until this day I always gave my first and last (João Martins - my full name is João Francisco Carvalho Andrade Martins) name for European flights and everything went great. While booking a flight to the US, I did the same, but I don't know if I should've done that.

My passport shows:

> GIVEN NAMES: **Joao** Francisco
>
> SURNAME: Carvalho Andrade **Martins**

But I just bought the tickets only with "Joao Martins". Am I in trouble?

Answer (score 4):

I could talk as my personal experience. I have one First Name and two Surnames. When I buy tickets to US, I fill only my First name and the last surname. It will be different from my passport. However, I never had any issue.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** The people who check you in for an international flight should be well aware of the naming conventions in other countries. There would not have been enough room in the ticket record for that many characters.

Of course, make sure the number matches.

Comment: Are you referring about the passport number? They didn't ask for it upon buying the tickets. The only numbers that match are the birth date.

Comment: They will ask. The US government likes to know in advance. Perhaps when you check in, assuming you do online check in.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus airlines also ask for passport numbers when travelers check in at the desk.  More precisely, they ask for the whole passport, from which they scan the number.