# Two letters of my first name transposed on boarding pass. Should I be worried?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, local-customs, tsa

My wife made a typo on my ticket where my name reads Micheal instead of Michael. Other than this everything is OK.

I was able to use the ticket when leaving the USA, as I did not need this ticket to pass through TSA and the airline did not care about the issue. I will now need the ticket to pass through airport security in Warsaw, and it is the ticket for my international flight.

I feel that I should be OK to get through the Warsaw airport, as from what I recall from flying in and out of Poland a few times, they are a bit more relaxed than the TSA.

What I am nervous about is getting back into the USA. If they check my boarding pass, they will notice the slight error in the spelling of my name. Although I will have the next boarding pass which states my name as Michael and 3 forms of ID (SS card, DL and passport).

Should I look into spending 100 euro extra to change my name, or just go with the current boarding pass?

Answer (score 2):

The only place where the name on your ticket/boarding card matters is at the *departure* airport when you're trying to board the flight. It matters there because the airline wants to check you're the person they were paid to transport.

Even so, I doubt the airline is going to make a fuss over what is obviously a simple typo in the passenger name.

Once you get on the plane and arrive in the US, all that matters to immigration is that you can prove that *you* should be allowed to enter; a (presumably US) passport will do that nicely. They don't care about boarding passes of arriving passengers; it is not their job to worry about the airlines' revenue management strategies.

Answer (score 1):

I could talk as my personal experience. I have one First Name and two Surnames. When I buy tickets to US, I fill only my First name and the last surname. It will be different from my passport. However, I never had any issue.

Another question as a reference -> [Travelling to US with United Airlines with only one first name and only one last name](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112925/travelling-to-us-with-united-airlines-with-only-one-first-name-and-only-one-last/112934#112934)

Answer (score 1):

Just a datapoint to contradict the previous answers. There was recently a report of WOW Air denying international boarding due to a missing middle name on a boarding pass (vs. their passport): http://www.foxnews.com/travel/2018/04/10/woman-kept-off-wow-flight-for-not-having-middle-name-on-boarding-pass.html

Based on this, I’d take the effort to contact the airline to try to correct the error or at least get assurance that it won’t be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have already contacted Swiss and they put a note into the system to make sure I dont have problems boarding the plane